# java exception: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: java, sql

i have the following exception:
[image]

here is the relevant code parts:
Server.Proxy.update_allLogOut: (line 65 is the while bracket)

```
    public void update_allLogOut ()
{
    try 
    {
        ResultSet rs;
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sysuser WHERE login=1");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE sysuser SET login=0");
        }
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

}
```

Server.Server.:

```
      public Server(int port) 
 {
    super(port);
    func.update_allLogOut();
  }
```

main:

```
Server sv = new Server(5555);
```

i must point out that 99% of times it runs with no exceptions.. but several times i get this exception that i cant figure out why it happens. any ideas? it is clear that something is done wrong yet all similar topics here have not given the answer in this case...

Comment: what is on line 65 in update_allLogOut  method??

Comment: @ronnjack what do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `stmt` to both iterate over the results of `SELECT` and to `UPDATE` inside the loop. This doesn't work since the moment you execute the `UPDATE`, the result set associated with the `SELECT` gets closed.

To fix, use two separate `Statement` objects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, that this block:

```
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sysuser WHERE login=1");
    while(rs.next())
    {
        stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE sysuser SET login=0");
    }
    rs.close();
```

is a good idea.
Why not just execute simple query: `UPDATE sysuser SET login=0 WHERE login=1`?

Furthermore, using same `stmt` inside `while` loop - it is rough mistake.